# What does the output of 'ss -s' mean?

Tags: linux, networking, bash, iproute2

I have a problem understanding the output of the Linux [`ss`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ss) (socket statistics) command. I can not understand the meaning of the output of `ss -s`

For example:

```
[root@dls2304-1 ~]# ss -s
Total: 973 (kernel 996)
TCP:   600 (estab 280, closed 73, orphaned 0, synrecv 0, timewait 0/0), ports 333

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
*         996       -         -
RAW       1         1         0
UDP       157       128       29
TCP       527       512       15
INET      685       641       44
FRAG      0         0         0
```

My questions:

What does `Total: 973 (kernel 996)` mean? What is `Total` and what is `kernel`? Why `Total` seems to be smaller than `kernel`?

In the line `TCP:   600 (estab 280, closed 73, orphaned 0, synrecv 0, timewait 0/0), ports 333`, what does the word `ports` mean?

And this:

```
Transport Total     IP        IPv6
*         996       -         -
```

What does the asterisk (`*`) mean?

They are way over my head. I can not find document about the spec of the output for `ss` command. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I am going to state explicitly I am really “winging” this answer. I have networking experience a systems administrator, but my networking knowledge is not as deep as most. So hopefully I will get some of this right. And if someone who knows better reads this, please comment or even edit to correct.

When you run the [`ss`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ss) (socket statistics) command with the `-s` flag that shows the socket status. So knowing that:

> What does `Total: 973 (kernel 996)` mean? What is `Total` and what is
>   `kernel`? Why `Total` seems to be smaller than `kernel`?

To my knowledge, system sockets don’t expire right away after use. So to the best of my knowledge the `973` is a reflection of total active sockets minus expired sockets, but the `996` connected to the kernel includes the `23` remaining stray sockets that the kernel has not gotten around to clean up yet. [This page on kernel tuning gives a nice overview](http://tweaked.io/guide/kernel/) of the concept of how the kernel deals with sockets and how one can tune a system to better manage sockets on the kernel level.

> In the line `TCP:   600 (estab 280, closed 73, orphaned 0, synrecv 0,
>   timewait 0/0), ports 333`, what does the word `ports` mean?

The `ports 333` just is a tally of all port activity on your system at that specific moment. The `333` matches the sum of `estab 280` and `closed 73`. Specifics about those ports would be summarized below that list. But in the context of sockets that line basically states there are `600` sockets available and of those `600`, `333` are in some way associated to ports on the system. For more details on what a socket is versus a port, read this excellent answer on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/152863).

> What does the asterisk (`*`) mean?

In the context of the example you show:

```
Transport Total     IP        IPv6
*         996       -         -
```

See how that `996` the kernel total in `Total: 973 (kernel 996)`? That `*` correlates to sockets that are simply open/managed regardless of of their transport layer on the kernel level.

But that said, yes… This is all quite confusing on a novice level.

Comment: Thank you very much for you explanation and sorry for late respond. After browsing the source code of iptable2, I found you are basically right and you enlightened me a lot. Just a reminder, **ports** is not always the sum of **estab** and **closed**. **ports** reflects total ports in use right now on the machine, which is read from /proc/slabstat. So **ports** includes some ports of astray sockets.

Comment: “The 333 matches the sum of estab 280 and closed 73”
The sum of 280 and 73 is 353 which is not equal to 333 :(